# Reject own pending edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently made a suggested edit to a question (nothing major, just fixed some formatting). However, while I was doing so, someone else (with edit privileges) did a better job of that. So now my suggested edit looks like I am actually removing indentation from perfectly well-formatted code - can I reject my own pending edit because someone else clearly did it better? Or should I just wait and assume that the edit will eventually be rejected on it's own?

Comment: Just wait. It will get handled, one way or the other.

Comment: @rene: Looks like you handled it yourself just a little while ago by adding the final reject vote. :-P Thanks